# How do I initialize an ILogger in a .NET 6 class library?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I've a class library, which is used by a console application. I now want to add a `ILogger<T>` via constructor injection in my class library. I came up with something like this:

```
public class Class1
{
    private readonly ILogger<Class1> _logger;

    public Class1(ILogger<Class1> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

Nevertheless I don't know how I could hand over the `ILogger<T>`.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 clazz = new Class1(?????);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can try to use [`ServiceCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) which can be restored from [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/)

`ServiceCollection` can register `Class1` class to DI Container and `ILogger<Class1>` might auto injected if we register our class correctly.

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddConsole());
services.AddTransient<Class1>();
ServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
Class1 clazz = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<Class1>();
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kxb0QH)

I would suggest using [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/) to implement our log mechanism which provides infrastructure default implementation by Microsoft.

In addition, a lot of popular open-source log projects would support and extend `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` like [Serilog.Extensions.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Extensions.Logging/3.1.1-dev-10301),[NLog.Extensions.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.Logging/)...

so that we can easy to change different logger architecture if that architecture extends `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`.

```
services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddNLog());
services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddSerilog());
```